# Stelford Titanium Calendar not adding events to ical on ios

Tags: ios, module, calendar, titanium

I have some code that is supposed to use the stelford calendar to add events to my ical on an iphone 3gs with ios 5.1.1 however when I test it out on the phone It doesn't add it to my calendar. If anyone could help that would be great!

```
//Calendar Dates
var sd = new Date();
sd.setYear(startYear);
sd.setMonth(startMonth);
sd.setDate(startDay);
sd.setHours(startHour);
sd.setMinutes(startMinute);

var ed = new Date();
ed.setYear(endYear);
ed.setMonth(endMonth);
ed.setDate(endDay);
ed.setHours(endHour);
ed.setMinutes(endMinute);

btn2.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var ticalendar = require("com.ti.calendar");

    var ev = ticalendar.createItem({
        title: meetName,
        startDate: sd,
        endDate: ed,
        location: meetLoc
    });

    var p = ev.saveEvent();
    Ti.API.info(p);
    alert('Event Saved to Your Calendar!');
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is you actual Error... plz attached Error...

Comment: I am not receiving an error it says there is none and gives me an event id and status of 1 however when I press that button to add to my calendar it doesn't add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
var sd = new Date();
var ed = new Date();
    ed = ed.setMinutes(59);


btn2.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var ticalendar = require("com.ti.calendar");

    var ev = ticalendar.createItem({
        title: "meetName",
        startDate: sd,
        endDate: ed,
        location: "meetLoc"
    });

    var p = ev.saveEvent();
    Ti.API.info(p);
if(p.error!="none"){

    alert("Error :- " + p.error );
}else{
    alert("Add Successfully");
}
    alert('Event Saved to Your Calendar!');
});
```

I think this is help for you Cheers:)

Comment: This also works but it wasn't my problem. I didn't know that the months are from 0-11 not 1-12. It was adding my events just a month later!

Comment: oh ... great... in Programming Language Array Always start with 0 index and Data return month's name in array so. this is started with 0 : Cheers...

Comment: i getting "No calendar has been set" error. i tried in iphone4, What should i do.?